# mutually recursive functions

Tags: java, mutual-recursion

I am trying to understand why the below functions are outputting zero for any input I give them. I would have thought that based on the recursive nature that inputting a 2 to function g, would produce 12. Any integer I seem to use for either function simply outputs 0. Can anyone point to where I am going wrong in my thought process?

```
public class dsdsfsd {
    public static int i(int n) {
        if (n == 0) return 0;
        return i(n-1) + g(n-1);
    }

    public static int g(int n) {
        if (n == 0) return 0;
        return g(n-1) + i(n);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 2;
        System.out.println(g(a));
        System.out.println(i(a));
        System.out.println(g(g(a)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure.  The only value these functions *can* return is 0.  That's the base case, and the higher cases do nothing but add up those zeroes.  Where do you see another value entering the equation?

Answer (score 2):

- If either function has zero as an argument, it returns 0.
- If it has any other value, it returns the sum of two recursive calls.
- The sum of two zeros is zero.

Where exactly do you expect the function to produce anything *but* zero?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not on the recurrence but on the initialization of your variables.

I reckon that you try to calculate some linked coefficients by the formulas:

- g(n) = g(n-1) + i(n)
- i(n) = i(n-1) + g(n-1)
- g(0) = 0
- i(0) = 0

However, as you initialized g and i to 0, i(1) = g(0) + i(0) = 0 + 0 = 0, and any values of g(n) or i(n) will be 0 for the same reason which is: you keep adding 0's and 0's.

Instead if you want to have a non-null result you should change at least one of your initialization, for example:

- g(0) = 1
- i(0) = 1

That way, you have i(1) = g(0) + i(0) = 1 + 1 = 2 and g(1) = g(0) + i(1) = 1 + 2 = 3.

This is more a mathematical issue in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce this to a single function for simplicity, since the mutual recursion is irrelevant:

```
public static int func(int n) {
     if (n == 0) return 0;
     return func(n-1);
}
```

Notice there are only 2 ways for this to return:

- It can return 0 directly in the base case
- It can return the result of recursing.

Think about that. At some point, it must stop recursing (or else it will run forever). What happens when the base case of 0 is returned? Your function turns into something like this (for imagining purposes only of course):

```
public static int func(int n) {
     if (n == 0) return 0;
     return 0;
}
```

Therefore, 0 is the only value your function(s) are capable of returning, since it's the only concrete value ever returned.